# Названия скал. Все ли слова с большой буквы?

Tags: названия

В названиях крымских скал все ли названия с большой буквы. Например, Золотые ворота (Ворота), Чертов палец (Палец).

Answer (score 2):

**Оба слова пишутся с прописной буквы.**

Основание: справочник Лопатина, § 169 прим.:

> Нарицательные существительные в составных географических названиях
> пишутся с прописной буквы, если они употреблены не в своем обычном
> значении, напр.: Новая Земля, Огненная Земля (архипелаги), Золотой Рог
> (бухта), Чешский Лес (горы), Белая Церковь, Минеральные Воды, Сосновый
> Бор, Вятские Поляны, Царское Село (города), Пушкинские Гэры, Камское
> Устье (поселки), Голодная Губа (озеро), Большой Бассейн (плоскогорье),
> Золотые Ворота (пролив), Кузнецкий Мост, Охотный Ряд, Земляной Вал
> (улицы), Никитские Ворота, Рогожская Застава (площади), Марьина Роща
> (район в Москве), Елисейские Поля (улица в Париже).